# Conditional formatting highlighting cells base on date range & reference values to another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, vba

I'm a very new to excel and I do not understand complex scripts hence I need help and step by step guide on how I can achieve the following below:

Data type = Tracking of sales proposals

Cell A = Stage of proposal (0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 90%, 100%)
Cell L = Expected close date

**Objective/final outcome:**

1. Highlight Cell L (red), For stage 0% - 75% if Cell L date is past dates (including today)
2. Highlight cell L (orange), For stage 0% - 75% if cell L date is 7 days before expected close date
3. Highlight cell L (yellow), For stage 0% -75% if cell L date is 14 days before expected close date

Comment: I'm not too sure how this works.. but I only added in 'Conditional-formatting' tag... the rest is added in by another user?

Comment: You don't need VBA for this, search for `Conditional Format`

Comment: @pnuts Technically I have the conditional formatting worked base on certain conditional values (date is between =today()+ & =today()+21 - if true, cell color = yellow. Date is between =today()+1 & =today()+7 - if true, cell color = orange. Date is less than or equal to =today() - if true, cell color = red. However it's highlighting all cells L whereas I only need cells to be highlighted on cell L if cell A value is = to the following: 75% - Negotiation, 50% - Proposal, 25% - Discussion, 0% - Prospecting.

Answer (score 0):

Select your column L, go to "Conditional Formatting", select "New Rule", select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". Under "Format values where this formula is true" type the following formula =AND($A1<=75%,$L1<=TODAY())   then click on Format, choose Fill Red. 
Add the other 2 formats as 2 more rules, changing the date conditions as needed. 
Make sure to delete unused rules, as too many rules will make the file big and slow, and it's a good practice anyway. 
Hope this helps.